# ESP 32 as WiFi client current drain strange behavior

Tags: esp32

I've configured my ESP32 board as WiFi client and, at the same time, I've measured current consumption.

I've noted that:

1. when the ESP32 is **not connected** to any WiFi AP , it drain about 140 mA
2. when it is succesfully connected to a WiFi AP it drain about 70 mA (*50% less than when it is disconnected from AP*).

I find this behavior very strange.
Any idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there alternative software you can try?

Comment: My guess is that your code behaves differently when connected to a WiFi AP than when not connected, perhaps executing some check in a tight loop rather than letting the task sleep, and that is responsible for the increase in power draw.

Comment: you mean "while trying to connect"?

Comment: @Juraj
If the AP  (acces point) is OFF, the ESP32 board drain 140 mA. When I start AP, the ESP board connect to it and halve its consumption (70mA).

Comment: you set the mode to SoftAP and it turns of the STA which automatically attempts to join the last WiFi network?